# Are "Statement and Declarations in Expressions" specific to GNU C?

Tags: c, standards, gnu, c99

Are [Statement and Declarations in Expressions](http://www.bris.ac.uk/acrc/RedHat/rhel-gcc-en-4/c-extensions.html) specific to GNU C ? Or this feature is also included in C99 standard ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a GCC extension.  (See the GCC docs, [e.g. here for gcc 4.3.3](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/C-Extensions.html), for a full list of GCC extensions; and the [C99 spec is available here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/standards.html).)

GCC will warn about such things if you use the `-pedantic -std=c99` flags, e.g.:

```
$ cat foo.c
int main(void)
{
  return ({ int a = 0; a; });
}
$ gcc -pedantic -std=c99 -c foo.c
foo.c: In function 'main':
foo.c:3: warning: ISO C forbids braced-groups within expressions
```

Comment: Is the feature included in the C99 standard as well ?

Answer (score 3):

While this is *not* a C99 standard, this extension is not *specific* to gcc either.

For instance, the [clang compiler](http://clang.llvm.org/) and [Intel C++ compiler](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/cpp/lin/compiler_c/bldaps_cls/common/bldaps_gcc_compat_comm.htm) support this extension.

Answer (score 1):

It's a GNU C extension.  That's what they mean by "may appear ... in **GNU C**." (my emphasis)

Comment: Is the feature included in the C99 standard as well ?

Comment: @AndreiCiobanu - no, it's limited to GNU C only (as opposed to standard C)