# warning "operation on <variable> may be undefined"

Tags: g++, warnings

When I use [overloading [][] operators in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657811) to create a minimal matrix class

```
class matrix {
private:
  vector<T> elems_;
  size_t         nrows_;
  size_t         ncols_;  
public:
  T const* operator[] ( size_t const r ) const { return &elems_[r * ncols_]; }
  T*       operator[] ( size_t const r )       { return &elems_[r * ncols_]; }  
  matrix ();
  matrix ( size_t const nr, size_t const nc ) 
    : elems_( nr * nc ), nrows_( nr ), ncols_( nc ) 
  { }
  matrix ( size_t const nr, size_t const nc, T const *data) 
    : elems_( nr * nc ), nrows_( nr ), ncols_( nc ) 
  { size_t ptr=0; 
    for (int i=0;i<nr;i++) 
        for (int j=0;j<nc;j++) 
             elems_[ptr] = data[ptr++]; 
  }
}
```

g++ returns the warning `operation on ‘ptr’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]`. In previous post
[Why I got "operation may be undefined" in Statement Expression in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838884) it is explained that `the last thing in the compound statement should be an expression followed by a semicolon` but not which purpose it serves. Does it mean that `g++` will always throw this warning for compound statements that have a for-loop at the end?

If so can anyone explain why this is useful? I cannot think of any reason why anyone should be advised against ending a compound statement with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `elems_[ptr] = data[ptr++]`, it is undefined whether `elems_[ptr]` is evaluated first or `data[ptr++]` is evaluated first. This is so, because `=` does not introduce a sequence point.

Depending on the order, `elems_[ptr] = data[ptr++]` yields different results. Hence the warning.

Comment: Thanks for this, just using the "long" form `elems_[ptr]=data[ptr];ptr++;` gets rid of the warning! That still leaves the ambiguity of (1) first determining the location `elems_[ptr]`, then getting the value `data[ptr]`, then copy the value to the location or (2) first getting the value `data[ptr]`, then determining the location `elems_[ptr]`, then copy the value to the location.

Comment: I just got the same warning.  I thought the right-of-equal equation is always evaluated first, then assigned to the left-of-equals.