# Purpose of Curly Brace Usage of C Code found in Linux (include/linux/list.h)?

Tags: c, linux, linked-list, curly-braces

I came across the following code within Linux (include/linux/list.h). I'm confused about line 713. In particular, I don't understand ({ n = pos->member.next; 1; }).

What is the curly braces doing? Why is there a '1' in this statement?

If someone could explain this particular line it would be much appreciated. Note, I don't need an explanation of how link lists and #defines work, etc.

```
704 /**
705  * hlist_for_each_entry_safe - iterate over list of given type safe against removal of list entry
706  * @pos:        the type * to use as a loop cursor.
707  * @n:          another &struct hlist_node to use as temporary storage
708  * @head:       the head for your list.
709  * @member:     the name of the hlist_node within the struct.
710  */
711 #define hlist_for_each_entry_safe(pos, n, head, member)                 \
712         for (pos = hlist_entry_safe((head)->first, typeof(*pos), member);\
713              pos && ({ n = pos->member.next; 1; });                     \
714              pos = hlist_entry_safe(n, typeof(*pos), member))
715
```

Comment: `({ /* code */ })` is a GNU extension, a statement-expression. The code in the braces is executed, and the value is the value of the last expression inside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a *statement expression*. It is a [gcc extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079721/are-statement-and-declarations-in-expressions-specific-to-gnu-c) and according to the documentation [6.1 Statements and Declarations in Expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html):

> The last thing in the compound statement should be an expression followed by a semicolon; the value of this subexpression serves as the value of the entire construct.

Which in the case, for the code:

```
({ n = pos->member.next; 1; })
```

the value would be `1`. According to the documentation:

> This feature is especially useful in making macro definitions “safe”  (so that they evaluate each operand exactly once).

It gives this example without using *statement expressions*:

```
#define max(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

versus this *safe* version, with the caveat that you know the type of the operands:

```
#define maxint(a,b) \
   ({int _a = (a), _b = (b); _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

This is one of the many [gcc extensions used in the Linux kernel](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gcc-hacks/).

Comment: @Will Anything that has side-effects risks having them applied twice. For example: `max(a++,b)` will expand to two a++'s, unlike a regular function call.

Answer (score 1):

This is a GNU language extension known as a [*statement expression*](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs); it's not standard C.