# C variable assigned with return value from scope block?

Tags: c, mono

I stumbled upon code which doesn't seem valid, but apparently is because it is sitting in [Mono codebase for already 2 years](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mono/utils/mono-memory-model.h). Below is small excerpt. How can result of macro "mono_atomic_load_acquire" be assigned to variable "count" in [unload_data_unref](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mono/metadata/appdomain.c)(..) I assume __tmp is what is being assigned, but I can't find any info of using scoping this way in C. Can anyone explain or give some useful link?

```
#define mono_atomic_load_acquire(target) ({ \
    typeof (*target) __tmp = *target;   \
    LOAD_ACQUIRE_FENCE; \
    __tmp; })

#define LOAD_ACQUIRE_FENCE MEMORY_BARRIER
#define MEMORY_BARRIER mono_memory_barrier ()

static inline void mono_memory_barrier (void)
{
    // platform specific code
}

unload_data_unref (unload_data *data)
{
    gint32 count;
    do {
        count = mono_atomic_load_acquire (&data->refcount);
        g_assert (count >= 1 && count <= 2);
        if (count == 1) {
            g_free (data);
            return;
        }
    } while (InterlockedCompareExchange (&data->refcount, count, count - 1) != count);
}
```

Comment: I just haven't seen anything like that. It's not a function, but a block of code where variable go out of scope after it. How can it return a value?

Comment: This is blocking me from compiling mono under Visual Studio 2012. How would I write it in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a GNU extension, they are called statement expressions (not to be confused with the standard C language construct called "expression statement"). In factm it is `__tmp` that's assigned. [Docs here.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html)

Answer (score 0):

So this is a `statement expression`. It is a  [`gcc extension`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079721/are-statement-and-declarations-in-expressions-specific-to-gnu-c) and according to the documentation [6.1 Statements and Declarations in Expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html):

> The last thing in the compound statement should be an expression followed by a semicolon; the value of this subexpression serves as the value of the entire construct.

In this case it would be `__tmp`. According to the documentation:

> This feature is especially useful in making macro definitions “safe”  (so that they evaluate each operand exactly once).

It gives this example without using `statement expressions`:

```
#define max(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

versus this `safe` version, with the caveat that you know the type of the operands:

```
#define maxint(a,b) \
   ({int _a = (a), _b = (b); _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```